# Where do I issue commands?

Tags: python, input, command, prompt, cx-freeze

When tools such as cx_freeze tell you to use a command such as "python setup.py build", where is this command issued? I have tried both the python command line and the Windows command prompt, but neither one worked with inputting that phrase.

Comment: "but neither one worked", what error did you see when you tried "`python setup.py build`" at the Windows command prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what :

1. This goes on the windows command prompt.
2. You first need to `cd` to the directory where your setup.py is situated.

For Eg: C:\folder\setup.py

On the command prompt :

- C:\
- cd folder
- python setup.py build

Now, this will call python and pass the file `setup.py` and asks to build it.

Comment: Hmm, curious. I could have sworn that I did exactly that before and it didn't work... Well, now I feel foolish. Much thanks.

Comment: No.. problems.. this happens to everyone of us. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You issue such commands from the command prompt.  You should make sure that you've changed into the directory containing `setup.py` before typing the command.

Answer (score 0):

It works from your shell or command prompt, but it assumes that you have followed [the appropriate guide(s)](http://docs.python.org/distutils/index.html) for generating a `setup.py` file for your code.